# create a copy of an excel template file from a list and rename according to a list

Tags: excel, vba

MY Question: Macro Needed

i have 2 excel files, the first is a master file that contains list of all the job#'s. the second file is a template that contains formulas.

First excel File looks like this:

ColumnA

```
Job# 1
Job# 2
Job# 3
Job# 4
```

the second file is a template that looks up the job and its details

What i want is a code that create an excel file for each job that is a copy of the template but i want to rename it as the Job# 1 , Job# 2 ...etc. in a specific folder.

The Tricky Part is that i do not want to overwrite the file if it already exists.

is this possible? if so any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You simple open the source file and loop through the list constructing a full file name (including path and name), check if a file with a specific name exists (using `DIR(<test_filename>)`) and if the result is `""`, save the open file with the new full name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code. It is a bit rough and untested, but should do the job. You need to have the Masterwork book in the same directory as the template.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyData()
Dim wksCurrent As Worksheet, wkbNew As Workbook
Dim rng As Range, c As Range, LastCell As Range
Dim wkbPath As String, wkbFileName As String, LFilename As String, wkbNewPath As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim lrow As Long, LastRowInput As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set wksCurrent = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

Set rng = Selection

On Error GoTo errHandler

wkbPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"
wkbNewPath = wkbPath & "JobTemplate.xlsx"

Set wkbNew = Workbooks.Open(wkbNewPath)

LastRowInput = wksCurrent.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

' If nothing is selected in column A
' GoTo Error Handling
If rng.Cells(1, 1) Is Nothing Then
GoTo errHandler
End If

For Each c In rng.Cells
lrow = wkbNew.Worksheets(1).Range("B1").Offset(wkbNew.Worksheets(1).Rows.Count - 1, 0).End(xlUp).Row

    wksCurrent.Range("A" & c.Row).Copy Destination:=wkbNew.Worksheets(1).Range("B" & lrow)
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

' Error Handling
exitHandler:

LFilename = wkbPath & wkbNew.Worksheets(1).Range("B" & lrow) & ".xlsx"
If Dir(LFilename) <> "" Then
    ChDir (wkbNewPath) 'To open in folder
    LFilename = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:="", FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls), *.xls")
End If

If (LFilename <> "" And LFilename <> "False") Then
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs LFilename
Else
    'filename is still empty - user may have cancelled GetSaveAsFilename Dialog
    'do something to handle this possibility...
    MsgBox "file was not saved!"
End If
Exit Sub
errHandler:
MsgBox "Please select cell(s) in column A", vbCritical, "Error"
Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Comment: Niclas this worked for me. Great job man. i just need to improve it a little. thanks a lot for the help so far. Things i want to improve:

1- it is only creating what you select from column A if you select the whole list it is still not creating it for all of them.

2- I dont want the process to stop just because there is a file already exists so if there is a check in place before creating the file to check for the job#.xlsm if its there skip it if not then create and go on. Thanks again Niclas great help always appreciated